# How to get an order's items from an Order ID? (OpenCart 2.0)

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am basically trying to get the items, their costs with an `order_id` for use in listing on an invoice email which will be sent to the client after purchase or in the future if need be.

Getting order information from the model `checkout/order` with `$this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);` doesn't seem to actually include item-specific information (like name, amount and cost), and thus I cannot finish the email.

Though, I have seen it in the database under the table `order_product`, which is filled by the same  `checkout/order` model file, but which `getOrder()` doesn't seem to actually get.

Will I need to make a separate model file to get item-specific info from an order or is there already something that does exactly that which I do not know of? (or am I reading code wrong somewhere?)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: hmm can you explain it a little bit more with more details? exactly what you need and where you need to store that information

Comment: I need item-specific information from an order (such as name, price, amount of each item) which will then be used to create an invoice email. I do not want to get it from `session` or `POST`, as I want to be able to use the invoice-creating event long after the order. (simply by giving it the `order_id`)

Comment: From where are you trying to access that information? from inside the admin panel or somewhere else? (which page exactly)

Comment: From a custom event-handler which is given the `order_id`. I already pull all other needed information from the database with the ID, `$order_info` just doesn't include item-specific info.

Comment: There's a `getOrderProducts()` method in the same model file. Call that with the order id

Comment: That would be in the admin side @JayGilford - looks like he's in the front end.

Comment: @billynoah - its in the catalog side too as you've got in your answer - though he's using the wrong model which I didn't spot

Comment: right... so many dang order.php models ;-)

Comment: Yep, I was indeed using the wrong `order.php` model file. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get product info from historical orders as you described, you want ***catalog/model/account/order.php***:

```
$this->load->model('account/order');
$products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($order_id);
```

And just for thoroughness I'd mention if you are dealing with an active cart you can use ***system/library/cart.php***:

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

Comment: I never noticed this function.. I'll have a check monday and will give you feedback then.

Comment: This is the same method used to list products when a logged in customer looks at details for an order in their order history.

Comment: It is exactly what I needed. I was searching in the `checkout/order.php` instead of `account/order.php`, which is why I couldn't find it. Thank you.